# Python class inheritance with changing default values

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have few classes that have same props and it will be much more of them so how I can make other class to pass that common props to each class but to use default values from `Props` class if I do not want to enter some of the arguments. So far if I do not enter  `anchor`, `layer` or `linetype_scale` argument I am getting error `TypeError: __init__() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'anchor', 'layer', and 'linetype_scale'`.

```
class Props():
    def __init__(self, anchor="CC", layer=0, linetype_scale=1):
        self.anchor = anchor
        self.layer = layer,
        self.linetype_scale = linetype_scale

class Rectangle(Props):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, anchor, layer, linetype_scale):
        super().__init__(anchor, layer, linetype_scale)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

class Square(Props):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, anchor, layer, linetype_scale):
        super().__init__(anchor, layer, linetype_scale)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width

class Circle(Props):
    def __init__(self, x, y, diametar, anchor, layer, linetype_scale):
        super().__init__(anchor, layer, linetype_scale)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.diametar = diametar
```

What I want to be able to do is to call class without passing arguments for example:

```
rect = Rectangle(10, 10, 20, 50)
```

but if i need  to change anything to be able to do this:

```
rect = Rectangle(10, 10, 20, 50, linetype_scale=5)
```

Comment: did you make a copy error? you `Props` class doesn't have an `__init__`, but instead has `init`

Comment: Sorry that  was  just copy  error I fixed that. I my code is `__init__`

Comment: You see how writing `def __init__(self, anchor="CC", layer=0, linetype_scale=1):` makes it possible not to need an explicit value for `anchor`, `layer` or `linetype_scale` when you create a `Props` directly? Did you try applying the same technique for the other `__init__` methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make use of [`**kwargs`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments), which are passed to `Props` if given, otherwise the defaults from `Props` are used:

```
class Props():
    def __init__(self, anchor="CC", layer=0, linetype_scale=1):
        self.anchor = anchor
        self.layer = layer,
        self.linetype_scale = linetype_scale


class Rectangle(Props):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height


rect1 = Rectangle(10, 10, 20, 50)
rect2 = Rectangle(10, 10, 20, 50, linetype_scale=5)

print(rect1.linetype_scale)
print(rect2.linetype_scale)
```

Out:

```
1
5
```